# ¿Como puedo hacer para que un FormControlName me reciba el Valor de Una Funcion en Angular y TypeScript?

Tags: html, nodejs, angular, typescript, aplicación-web

Estoy creando un sistema de gestión de pacientes con Angular y TypeScript y estoy utilizando `FormControlName` como lo muestro en el siguiente código:

```
ngOnInit() {

    this.formularioPaciente = this.fb.group({
      TipoDocumento: ['', Validators.required],
      NumDocumento: ['', Validators.required],
      urlImg: [''],
      PNombre: ['', Validators.required],
      SNombre: [''],
      PApellido: ['', Validators.required],
      SApellido: ['', Validators.required],
      Genero: ['', Validators.required],
      FechaNacimiento: ['', Validators.required],
      Edad: [] ,
      EstadoCivil: ['', Validators.required],
      RH:['', Validators.required],
      EPS: [''],
      Departamento: ['', Validators.required],
      Municipio: ['', Validators.required],
      Zona: ['', Validators.required],
      Barrio: ['', Validators.required],
      Direccion: [''],
      Telefono: [''],
      Email: [''],
      NomPadre: [''],
      NomMadre: ['']   
    })
  }
```

El punto es que para calcular el valor de el Campo Edad estoy utilizando la siguiente funcion valiendome de la libreria moments js:

```js
calcularA(){
    this.formularioPaciente.value.FechaNacimiento = moment(new Date(this.formularioPaciente.value.FechaNacimiento));
    let fechafin = moment(Date.now());
    let diff = fechafin.diff(this.formularioPaciente.value.FechaNacimiento, 'year');
    return diff;
  }
```

como puedo hacer para asignarle el Valor de mi funcion `calcularA()` al campo `Edad` de mi `FormControlName` intente de la siguiente forma:

`Edad:[this.calcularA()]` pero me genera un error que me dice valor is undefined, Por favor ayudenme estoy atascado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes modificar el valor de cualquier FormControl usando su método [`setValue`](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl#setvalue):

```
miFormulario.controls[<form_control_name>].setValue(...);
```

o de un modo más elegante (esto es opinable, pero a mi me lo parece):

```
miFormulario.get(<form_control_name>).setValue(...);
```

Por lo tanto, en tu caso puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
calcularA(){
    this.formularioPaciente.value.FechaNacimiento = moment(new Date(this.formularioPaciente.value.FechaNacimiento));
    let fechafin = moment(Date.now());
    let diff = fechafin.diff(this.formularioPaciente.value.FechaNacimiento, 'year');
    //con esto debería ser suficiente
    this.formularioPaciente.controls['Edad'].setValue(diff);
    return diff;
}
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias Crack Solucionado